# What does mb_internal_encoding() actually mean?

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8

[According to the PHP website](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-internal-encoding.php) it does this:

> **`encoding`** is the character encoding name used for the HTTP input
>   character encoding conversion, HTTP output character encoding
>   conversion, and the default character encoding for string functions
>   defined by the mbstring module. You should notice that the internal
>   encoding is totally different from the one for multibyte regex.

But I think that explanation is not enough to understand to me.

Once I requested some APIs with CURL in PHP. And I was working with parsing the response data. The response header contains `Content-Length`. So I believed that `Content-Length` shows exactly right value. Also, the result value of `mb_strlen($responseData)` is same as `Content-Length` value.

If I set the internal encoding value like `mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8')`, by the way, the result value of `mb_strlen($responseData)` is not same as before!.
Actually, the value is smaller than before.

My web server encoding, file encoding and accept encoding are all setted to UTF-8.

Why this problem happened?

Comment: There is no problem. The length of the decoded text was returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP treats strings as *byte arrays*, just as dumb collection of bytes. It does not know about encodings or "characters". The mb_* functions are a set of tools that are encoding aware and can treat strings on a character-by-character basis. For example, the string "漢字" in UTF-8 is 6 bytes long but represents only two characters. To be able to treat a string on a character by character basis, the mb_* functions need to know what encoding the given string is in. Every mb_* accepts an `$encoding` parameter, so you can tell it that. E.g.:

```
mb_strlen('漢字', 'UTF-8')  // 2
```

To set this encoding globally once and for all and not having to pass it into every function, there's `mb_internal_encoding`. It simply remembers the encoding setting, and every function that wants to can get this setting from it. The manual details which functions make use of it.

Your particular "issue" is that the HTTP Content-Length header designates the content length in bytes. The value is encoding agnostic, in fact its sole purpose is to alert the client to the size *in bytes* of the payload that will follow. This payload could be anything, so the size is given in bytes. The result will be different if you're interpreting it as characters in a given encoding.

For more basics, see [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/).

Answer (score 1):

Content-Length is the response size in **bytes**. In ASCII, Content-Length == character-count. In UTF-8, a single character can be made up of multiple bytes, therefore character-count will be the equal to or less than Content-Length.

For example:

`A` in ASCII = `0x41` (One byte)

`€` in UTF-8 = `0x20A0` (Two bytes)

`mb_strlen` returns the number of characters (not the number of bytes) for a given encoding type.

```
strlen("€")
>> 2
mb_strlen("€", 'UTF-8')
>> 1
strlen("A")
>> 1
mb_strlen("A", 'UTF-8')
>> 1
```